# Photo contest form

Tags: categorization, uploading, photos

I'm in some trouble trying to find out how to make a photo contest form where there are different categories and x numbers of files for each category, every file has a text input so they can give the photo a title. but to find a UX & UI design for it is harder than I believed.

First I made this, but that not so good again right?

[image]

The biggest problem with this is, that the user needs to scroll and read every category to find the those the user wanna join.. and the multiplied "upload" button there will be nice to cut out in a way so the user doesn't believe that he/she only need to push one of them but all of them to upload each category

Any there has an idea for a design?

> **PS:** First time I use UX on StackExchange so if the post missing something just say it and I will try to fix it

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about a page becoming too huge with all these different options on it - split it up.

Make page 1 about picking a topic.

Make page 2 about uploading the image.

It's all about the funnel. You want users to do what they're looking to do. That means accommodating their journey towards the end. Sometimes that means asking large segmenting questions first to sift them down into the right silo. And sometimes you have to do that multiple times to get them to the right portion of your app/site.

Comment: will this http://imgur.com/a/jn1Po category design be a good solution?

Comment: Or you can make this one page, but don't show the upload fields until user select the category.

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor no, it's a bad way to do this, because plus sign is ambiguous. I'd say keep it simple: if you want one category, use radio buttons; if there are many, use checkboxes.

Comment: @Runnick so they select what categories they wanna have? or they click on a category and then it popup with the upload fields ?

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor you can present form with only one section first: select the category. Then you show uploads at the bottom (I wouldn't recommend pop-ups) as a separate section. This of course depends on whether they can select one or more categories.

Comment: @Runnick I have made a update of the design http://imgur.com/8TUcNcD is that what you mean?